# SQL code to find if a series of lists do NOT contain a particular value

Tags: sql, missing-data

I have two tables

**Jobs**

```
+-----+------+
| Job | Name |
+-----+------+
|   1 | Foo  |
|   2 | Bar  |
|   3 | Baz  |
|   4 | Qwe  |
+-----+------+
```

**Job_Operations**

```
+-----+--------------+
| Job | Work_Center  |
+-----+--------------+
|   1 | SomeCenter   |
|   1 | Full Kit     |
|   2 | SomeCenter   |
|   3 | SomeCenter   |
|   3 | Full Kit     |
+-----+--------------+
```

The tables are linked on the `Job` column. How can I find the entries in `Jobs` **without** a corresponding 'Full Kit' entry in `Job_Operations`?

**Desired Results**

```
+-----+------+
| Job | Name |
+-----+------+
|   2 | Bar  |
|   4 | Qwe  |
+-----+------+
```

Comment: We really don't need to know the stuff in the first 4 paras! Nor do I want to parse the table structures out of narrative text. What would be much more useful would be example tabular data for `Jobs` and `Job_Operations` including an example of one with full kit and one without and a short explanation that you are trying to find ones without  'Full Kit' along with desired results

Comment: Please give us only the technical details. Currently this is hard to read!

Comment: I've rewritten your question for you to exclude the irrelevant information

Comment: I apologize.  Totally new here.  To Martin Smith...That rewrite was completely and totally awesome!!!! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
   Select * from
    (
    select Jobs.* , job_Operations.Work_Center as wc
    from Jobs
    left join Job_Operations on Jobs.Job=Job_Operations.Job and Job_Operations.Work_Center='Full Kit'
    ) as sub1 where wc is null
```

In the subselect *left join* tells the SQL server to give me a row for every row in the Jobs table, even if it does not find a corresponding value in the job_Operations. From job_Operations only rows that contain your 'Full Kit' are regarded for the join. If the join fails, SQLsefer just returns a null for the fields in job_Operations. The outer select just fetches those rows.

Another way is to use Exists, see how that works in the other answer. But if you want to learn SQL try to get an understanding of how left, right inner and outer/full join work.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a straight forward `NOT EXISTS` query

```
SELECT J.*
FROM   Jobs J
WHERE  NOT EXISTS(SELECT *
                  FROM   Job_Operations JO
                  WHERE  JO.Job = J.Job
                         AND JO.Work_Center = 'Full Kit')
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution in code below.
Also keep in mind that "working" doesn't meant "high performance".
Check [SQL-plan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_plan) on your specific DB.

```
select j.* 
from job j
where j.job not in (select jo.job 
                    from Job_Operations jo 
                    where jo.Work_Center = 'Full Kit');
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code only answers can almost always be improved by adding some explanation of how and why they work.

Comment: Thank you @Midiparse! Of course you're right. Done!